# Knockout's foreach wont iterate through an array

Tags: knockout.js, pager

I'll start presenting my HTML and View Model:

HTML:

```html
<div data-bind="with: chosenDevice">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3 data-bind="text: name"></h3>
    </div>

    <p>
        <span data-bind="text: attrs().length"></span>
    </p>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: attrs()">
        <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The HTML is bound to `chosenDevice` which is a `DeviceViewModel` object.

View Model:

```
function DeviceViewModel(device) {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable(device.name);
    self.attrs = ko.observableArray([{name: "test1"}, {name: "test2"}, {name: "test3"}]);
}
```

It is possible print name `text: name`, and also attrs `text: attrs` which prints: `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. When I log the object to the console all the data is present.

But when I try to use `foreach: attrs()` nothing happens? (I would like a list of `test1, test2, test3`).

I have simplified the example to make it easier to understand, I can of course post the full version.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you put together a jsFiddle?

Comment: Your code is working fine.... http://jsfiddle.net/XzsR3/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XzsR3/2/ - Can't get it to run on jsfiddle, as I mentioned before I can make it print everything other then attrs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is you're applying bindings to `viewModel`, so Knockout is throwing on not being able to find `chosenDevice` referenced in your `with:` binding.

I tooled around with your code a little [here](http://jsbin.com/evIwuzox/1/edit?html,js,output) by applying bindings instead to `viewModel.devices`. Without having the `pager` dependencies I don't think there's enough information to make a working demo, but with my change I'm not getting any JavaScript errors.